# dice score confusion based on image mask thresholds

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am trying to train a [slightly modified version of this UNet](https://github.com/mirzaevinom/prostate_segmentation/blob/master/codes/train.py) architecture for medical image segmentation.

I now am a bit confused about the functionality of line `88` in the train.py file.  `img_masks = np.array(img_masks > 0.45, dtype=int)`.

Could someone explain why there's a thresholding being done on the masks if the masks is either `0` or `1`! what does this achieve?

another observation I have while training with that line included is that my `dice coefficient scores` are very low in each epoch (Around `1e-4`) and commenting the thresholding out, My dice coeff jumps above `1` which as to my understanding dice score should be between `0` and `1`.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I assume the >0.45 exists to turn 0 into False and 1 into True, so you have a boolean array.

Comment: I am thinking the same since 0s might not be perfect 0.00...